# Background Process stops after input

Tags: bash, jobs, nodemon

I am trying to run nodemon in the background using

```
nodemon index.js &
```

nodemon outputs its initialization

```
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
listening on port 8080
```

no prompt is given, however, any command will run
(after pressing enter the first time the prompt is shown)
running `cd` causes bash to output:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 nodemon index.js  (wd: ~/foo/bar)
(wd now: ~)
```

showing that nodemon has stopped running

### Help me please

From my understanding bash should put the program in the background and, much like all other processes constantly running in the background, user input should stop influencing this process's behavior.

Should this be happening?
Am I missing something?
How can I run a program in the background properly?
Thank you all for your interest and time.

### Additional

I've found that repeatedly pressing `enter` will cause the job to stop with slightly different output:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 nodemon index.js
```

This only occurs if the `enter` key is pressed more than once. Sometimes it happens after 1 more press and other times it occurs after many more. There is no clear pattern in the number of presses

The job stops in the same way after `baz: command not found`

Comment: does `nodemon` read from **stdin** when running? according to bash manual: "Only **foreground**  processes are  allowed  to  read  from the terminal. Background processes which attempt to read from the terminal are sent a  **SIGTTIN** signal by the kernel's terminal driver, which, unless caught, **suspends** the process."

Answer (score 1):

Your program is being launched in the background as expected, and is indeed disconnected from user input. However, when you background a process it looks like the job control output is *paused* until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Try with for example `sleep 1 &` - A line like

> [1]+  Done                    sleep 1

will appear when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> **after** the background process finishes.

I suspect this may be happening to avoid outputting lines onto the screen while the user is trying to type another command.